# Spring Boot 2.0.0 , DataSourceBuilder not found in autoconfigure jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, spring2.x, spring-autoconfiguration

We are upgrading our existing `Spring Boot (1.5)` application to `2.0.0`.

We connect with multiple databases and use the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder` class.

I added the dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',
name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure',
version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
```

However, I am not able to compile the project: This class (`DataSourceBuilder`) does not exist in the 2.0.0 version jar.

In order to rule out gradle issues, I manually downloaded the jar and added it to the `classpath`. This class does not exist in the version.

Also extracted and searched the jar but this class is missing. 
Can anyone help me resolve it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The class was moved to another package. Its FQN is now `org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DataSourceBuilder.html

Answer (score 2):

Old class (Spring Boot 1.x)

```java
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder
```

New class (Spring Boot 2.x)

```java
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
```